# array type variable name created programmatically?

Tags: arrays, variables, ada, named

In Ada, I wish to create 10 two dimensional arrays of type array (0..9) Integer, creating 10 x 10 arrays of cells, which I will manipulate by indices. I want to be able to address each of the 10 layers separately, ideally by hybrid variable name like “layer_(i)” (row, col) := xxx, rather than having to access each layer_x by its static name like “layer_1” or “layer_2”, so I could run the same procedure algorithm against each layer and just vary my indices to suit each layer.

I have:

```
type grid is array (0..9) of Integer, (0..9) of integer;
layer_1, layer_2, layer_3, layer_4, layer_5,
  layer_6, layer_7, layer_8, layer_9, layer_0: grid;
```

Is there anyway I can create a variable of type grid, dynamically so that i can address it by “layer_”(x) rather than the full static name “layer_1” ?

======
After posting this, I realized one possible solution, though it does not directly address the specifics in the question, but an alternative solution.

I could create a three dimensional array, or an array of the two dimensional arrays, I could address as block(l,r,c) l for layer, r for row, and c for column, and not have full variable names like Layer_1, layer_2, etc.In either case, I will have 1,000 cells. Maybe there is no way around this, when thinking of the structure in arrays, though arrays seems the first test choice rather than a list of cells, which would involve some referenceing of prior and following cells that would be hard for human conceptualization, but fine for the machine.

=====
And, thinking further I see I don’t want a three dimensional array, but a single 1 dimensional array of 10 instances of the two dimension 10 x 10 arrays will work. I can address with 3 nested loops and use the same code pretty much when manipulating the 100 cells in each 10 by 10 array, depending on the primary array of 10x10 arrays and have immediate access to every cell in every 10 by 10 grid with loop varibles l,r,c.

Comment: You can also create arrays of arrays, and that's probably what I'd do here. `layers : array(0 .. 9) of grid;` layers(2) := layers(3); layers(4)(5,6) := 7; etc.

Comment: Thanks Simon: that’s what I have settled on to try, a one dimensional array of a two dimension array. Somehow it seems a little easier to manipulate than a 3-dimension arrary, as I am new to Ada.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't all that clear, but first you talk about about two-dimensional arrays of cells:

```ada
type Coordinates is [some discrete subtype];
type Cell is [some type];

type Grid is array (Coordinates, Coordinates) of Cell;
```

And layers of these:

```ada
type Layer_Indices is [some discrete subtype];

type Layers is array (Layer_Indices range <>) of Grid;
```

Comment: I got this doing what I want, for now at least, as it is a learning creating for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a vector for your layer index.  Vectors are indexible and dynamic.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Containers.Vectors; use Ada.Containers;

procedure Hello is

    type Grid is array (1..10,1..10) of Integer;

    package Grid_Vectors is new Vectors(Positive,Grid);

    subtype Vector is Grid_Vectors.Vector;

    Layers : Vector;

    procedure Print(The_Grid : Grid) is
    begin
        for x in The_Grid'Range(1) loop
            for y in The_Grid'Range(2) loop
                Put(Integer'Image(The_Grid(x,y)) & " "); -- print each one'
            end loop;
            New_Line;
        end loop;   
    end Print;

begin

  Put_Line("Hello, world!");

  -- add a lot of layers
  for Index in 1..20 loop
      declare
        New_Grid : Grid := (others => (others => Index));
      begin
        Layers.Append(New_Grid);
      end;
  end loop;

  -- make some sort of adjustment to a specific layer
  Layers(3)(1,3) := 23;

  -- Print the grid
  Print(Layers(3));

end Hello;
```